# Display loading while webservice is running

Tags: jquery, ajax

On the initial request to a page, I trigger a webservice and want to display a loading message.
When the page has finished loading, I want to remove the waiting message from screen, but display it again when a change event in a checkbox triggers an Ajax call with another loading message.

This code is not behaving to the given spec:

```
$(document).ready(
    $(function() {
     $('#loadingDiv').hide();

      $('#productsDropDown')
         .change(function() {
            var prodValue = $(this).val();
            $('#proddate').load('getpdate.php', {prod: prodValue });
    }); 

    $('#loadingDiv')
        .ajaxStart(function() {
            $(this).show();
        })
        .ajaxStop(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        })    
    ;   
    });
);
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rearrange your code a bit, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#loadingDiv').hide();
  $('#productsDropDown').change(function() {
    var prodValue = $(this).val();
    $('#proddate').load('getpdate.php', {prod: prodValue });
  }); 

  $('#loadingDiv').ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).show();
  }).ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Currently you have this:

```
$(document).ready(
    $(function() {
    });
);
```

`document.ready` takes a function, you're passing it a jquery element.   `$(function() { })` is equivalent to wrapping it in `$(document).ready(function() { })` already ([see details here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)), no need to wrap it twice.

Comment: thanks. that's the explanation... I got the same result by trial and error

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var loader = $('#loadingDiv');
    loader.hide();


    $('#productsDropDown').change(function() {
        var prodValue = $(this).val();
        loader.show();
        $('#proddate').load('getpdate.php', {prod: prodValue }, function() {
            loader.hide();
        });
    });
);
```